# "Bounty awarded by Community"

Tags: support, bounties, community-user

I just found a good question via Google. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686331/update-the-css-of-a-website-without-refreshing-the-page/12835037#12835037) answer which links to a self-made project by the user. It has awarded a bounty worth 50 rep by the **Community ♦** user.

But how can this user award bounties? How is this possible that, or when does, this bot award bounties?

Comment: When the bounty offerer disapears and doesnt award the bounty the community user awards half (to the most upvoted assuming score> 2